# Multiple List Sections in NavitagionSplitView Sidebar Only Shows a Single Item

Tags: list, macos, swiftui

I'm having a problem displaying all the list elements inside a list when there are multiple sections in the sidebar.

Here is an example code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                Section("Test 1") {
                    List(0...20, id: \.self) { i in
                        Text("\(i)")
                    }
                }
                
                Section("Test 2") {
                    List(21...50, id: \.self) { i in
                        Text("\(i)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.sidebar)
        } detail: {
            Text("Details")
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get two sections; however the list under them are only showing a single item instead of all.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Sidebar List with Multiple Sections Issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing this issue because you are trying to create a nested `List` inside the section of `List`. Inside the section of the list, you need to use `ForEach` to loop through your data instead of creating a nested `List`.

```
List {
    Section("Test 1") {
        ForEach(0...20, id: \.self) { i in
            Text("\(i)")
        }
    }
    
    Section("Test 2") {
        ForEach(21...50, id: \.self) { i in
            Text("\(i)")
        }
    }
}
.listStyle(.sidebar)
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what is happening :/